# findBy from repository trigger Internal error but not local

Tags: php, symfony

I'm quite lost with this one...I don't know what could possibly be wrong.

I have this piece of code which simply look for all messages from a place.
The place cannot be null as you can see.

In dev mode, I have no error.
In prod mode, the findBy triggers an internal error.
I'm sure this is it, because I can go into the first commented Json return with no error, but I can't reach the second one.

I'm also sure the error is on the findBy and not the repository because I have tried to separate in two lines and there is no error wuth the getRepository.

```
    if (!isset($place)) {
        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => "Place invalide"
        ]);
    }
    /*return new JsonResponse([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => "test0",
    ]);*/

    $messages_place = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:MessagePlace')->findBy(array('idPlace' =>$place));
    return new JsonResponse([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => "test",
    ]);
```

In my MessagePlace entity I have

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Place
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Place")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_place", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idPlace;
```

I can't understand why this piece of code would trigger an error 500 on server but not in localhost.

Thanks for your assistance.

EDIT: My bad problem solved, I had a typo issue in my MessagePlace I was querying an id_image instead of is_image...Sorry.

Comment: Can you check de Symfony log?

Comment: Well...sadly I can't, my ssh access is restricted; I have access to var/log but not to var/log/mysql

Comment: if it is a 500 error , you won't need mysql error log, just look in apache/nginx error log

Comment: Is that field new? Have you updated the bbdd? Have you clean cache?

Comment: Cache got cleared and the field isn't new. I can't check apache log neither, the apache2 folder in the log folder is restricted too :( - EDIT; I have access to the database and the field are the same in localhost and server database. Same as the entity.

Comment: Can you switch APP_ENV to prod in your local machine and run the code for seeing if this is happen in prod mode or only in prod server?

Comment: problem solved see edit.

Answer (score 1):

"The place cannot be null as you can see." 
JoinColumn default value for "nullable" settings is true so it can be null.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_joincolumn

Comment: Okay, but what I mean by that is: It can be null, but it's not null in this specific case. Otherwise I would have trigger an error before.